# Sentinel Failed to resolve hostname redis

Tags: java, spring-boot, kubernetes, redis, redis-sentinel

Dears,

I tried to access remote redis cache services from redis sentinel services for high availability. But sentinel server couldnt resolve redis host name.

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: No such host is known (redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local)
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java)
    at java.net.InetAddress$PlatformNameService.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:929)
    ... 38 frames excluded
Wrapped by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:78)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    ... 6 frames excluded
    ... 28 common frames omitted`
```

Also I see above the log on sentinel services like as the follows

```
1:X 12 Sep 2023 21:56:50.711 # Failed to resolve hostname 'redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local'
1:X 12 Sep 2023 21:56:51.773 # Failed to resolve hostname 'redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local'
1:X 12 Sep 2023 21:56:52.806 # Failed to resolve hostname 'redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local'
1:X 12 Sep 2023 21:56:53.838 # Failed to resolve hostname 'redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local'
1:X 12 Sep 2023 21:56:54.908 # Failed to resolve hostname 'redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local'
1:X 12 Sep 2023 21:56:55.914 # Failed to resolve hostname 'redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local'
1:X 12 Sep 2023 21:56:56.925 # Failed to resolve hostname 'redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local'
1:X 12 Sep 2023 21:56:57.967 # Failed to resolve hostname 'redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local'
1:X 12 Sep 2023 21:56:59.037 # Failed to resolve hostname 'redis-0.redis.xxxx-service-platform.svc.cluster.local'
```

Could you help me how to solve the problem?

I tried too much configuration but they didnt work, Sentinel and redis works the same cluster but on remote server, but sentinel should solve redis hostname

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: redis-config-map
data:
  # Variable needed for sentinel init container
  REDIS_NODES: "redis-0.redis,redis-1.redis,redis-2.redis"

  # Config used in all redises
  redis.conf: |
    # Redis configuration file example.
    # ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    bind 0.0.0.0
    # Protected mode is a layer of security protection, in order to avoid that
   
    # Close the connection after a client is idle for N seconds (0 to disable)
    timeout 300
    
    # A reasonable value for this option is 300 seconds, which is the new
    # Redis default starting with Redis 3.2.1.
    tcp-keepalive 30
   
    # Configure allowed ciphers.  See the ciphers(1ssl) manpage for more information
    # about the syntax of this string.
    #
    # Note: this configuration applies only to <= TLSv1.2.
    #
    # tls-ciphers DEFAULT:!MEDIUM
    # Configure allowed TLSv1.3 ciphersuites.  See the ciphers(1ssl) manpage for more
    # information about the syntax of this string, and specifically for TLSv1.3
    # ciphersuites.
    #
    # tls-ciphersuites TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    # When choosing a cipher, use the server's preference instead of the client
    # preference. By default, the server follows the client's preference.



    # verbose (many rarely useful info, but not a mess like the debug level)
    # notice (moderately verbose, what you want in production probably)
    # warning (only very important / critical messages are logged)
    loglevel notice
    # Specify the log file name. Also the empty string can be used to force
    # Redis to log on the standard output. Note that if you use standard
    # output for logging but daemonize, logs will be sent to /dev/null
    logfile ""
    # To enable logging to the system logger, just set 'syslog-enabled' to yes,
    # and optionally update the other syslog parameters to suit your needs.
    # syslog-enabled no
    # Specify the syslog identity.
    # syslog-ident redis
    # Specify the syslog facility. Must be USER or between LOCAL0-LOCAL7.
    # syslog-facility local0
    # Set the number of databases. The default database is DB 0, you can select
    
    # ASCII art logo in startup logs by setting the following option to yes.
    always-show-logo yes
    ################################ SNAPSHOTTING  ################################
   
    #
    # RDB files created with checksum disabled have a checksum of zero that will
    # tell the loading code to skip the check.
    rdbchecksum yes
    # The filename where to dump the DB
    # dbfilename "dump.rdb"
    # Remove RDB files used by replication in instances without persistence
    # enabled. By default this option is disabled, however there are environments
    # where for regulations or other security concerns, RDB files persisted on
    # disk by masters in order to feed replicas, or stored on disk by replicas

    #
    # Note that you must specify a directory here, not a file name.
    dir "/data"
   
    # When a replica loses its connection with the master, or when the replication
    
    
    # With slow disks and fast (large bandwidth) networks, diskless replication
    # works better.
    repl-diskless-sync no
    # When diskless replication is enabled, it is possible to configure the delay
    
    repl-diskless-sync-delay 5
    
    

    repl-diskless-load disabled
    # Replicas send PINGs to server in a predefined interval. It's possible to
    # change this interval with the repl_ping_replica_period option. The default
    # value is 10 seconds.
    #
    appendonly no
    # repl-ping-replica-period 10
    # The following option sets the replication timeout for:
    #
    
    # It is important to make sure that this value is greater than the value
    # specified for repl-ping-replica-period otherwise a timeout will be detected
    # every time there is low traffic between the master and the replica.
    #
    # repl-timeout 60
    
    # Linux kernels using a default configuration.
    #
    # If you select "no" the delay for data to appear on the replica side will
    # be reduced but more bandwidth will be used for replication.
    #
    # By default we optimize for low latency, but in very high traffic conditions
    # or when the master and replicas are many hops away, turning this to "yes" may
    # be a good idea.
    repl-disable-tcp-nodelay no
    # Set the replication backlog size. The backlog is a buffer that accumulates
    # replica data when replicas are disconnected for some time, so that when a
    # replica wants to reconnect again, often a full resync is not needed, but a
    # partial resync is enough, just passing the portion of data the replica
    # missed while disconnected.
    #
    # The bigger the replication backlog, the longer the time the replica can be
    # disconnected and later be able to perform a partial resynchronization.
    #
    # The backlog is only allocated once there is at least a replica connected.
    #
    # repl-backlog-size 1mb
    # After a master has no longer connected replicas for some time, the backlog
    # will be freed. The following option configures the amount of seconds that
    # need to elapse, starting from the time the last replica disconnected, for
    # the backlog buffer to be freed.
    #
    # Note that replicas never free the backlog for timeout, since they may be
    # promoted to masters later, and should be able to correctly "partially
    # resynchronize" with the replicas: hence they should always accumulate backlog.
    #
    # A value of 0 means to never release the backlog.
    #
    # repl-backlog-ttl 3600
    # The replica priority is an integer number published by Redis in the INFO
    # output. It is used by Redis Sentinel in order to select a replica to promote
    # into a master if the master is no longer working correctly.
    #
    # A replica with a low priority number is considered better for promotion, so
    # for instance if there are three replicas with priority 10, 100, 25 Sentinel
    # will pick the one with priority 10, that is the lowest.
    #
    # However a special priority of 0 marks the replica as not able to perform the
    # role of master, so a replica with priority of 0 will never be selected by
    # Redis Sentinel for promotion.
    #
    # By default the priority is 100.
    replica-priority 100
    # It is possible for a master to stop accepting writes if there are less than
    # N replicas connected, having a lag less or equal than M seconds.
    #
    # The N replicas need to be in "online" state.
    #
    # The lag in seconds, that must be <= the specified value, is calculated from
    # the last ping received from the replica, that is usually sent every second.
    #
    # This option does not GUARANTEE that N replicas will accept the write, but
    # will limit the window of exposure for lost writes in case not enough replicas
    # are available, to the specified number of seconds.
    #
    # For example to require at least 3 replicas with a lag <= 10 seconds use:
    #
    # min-replicas-to-write 3
    # min-replicas-max-lag 10
    #
    # Setting one or the other to 0 disables the feature.
    #
    # By default min-replicas-to-write is set to 0 (feature disabled) and
    # min-replicas-max-lag is set to 10.
    # A Redis master is able to list the address and port of the attached
    # replicas in different ways. For example the "INFO replication" section
    # offers this information, which is used, among other tools, by
    # Redis Sentinel in order to discover replica instances.
    # Another place where this info is available is in the output of the
    # "ROLE" command of a master.
    #
    # The listed IP and address normally reported by a replica is obtained
    # in the following way:
    #
    #   IP: The address is auto detected by checking the peer address
    #   of the socket used by the replica to connect with the master.
    #
    #   Port: The port is communicated by the replica during the replication
    #   handshake, and is normally the port that the replica is using to
    #   listen for connections.
    #
    # However when port forwarding or Network Address Translation (NAT) is
    # used, the replica may be actually reachable via different IP and port
    # pairs. The following two options can be used by a replica in order to
    # report to its master a specific set of IP and port, so that both INFO
    # and ROLE will report those values.
    #
    # There is no need to use both the options if you need to override just
    # the port or the IP address.
    #
    # replica-announce-ip 5.5.5.5
    # replica-announce-port 1234
    ############################### KEYS TRACKING #################################
    # Redis implements server assisted support for client side caching of values.
    # This is implemented using an invalidation table that remembers, using
    # 16 millions of slots, what clients may have certain subsets of keys. In turn
    # this is used in order to send invalidation messages to clients. Please
    # to understand more about the feature check this page:
    #
    #   https://redis.io/topics/client-side-caching
    #
    # When tracking is enabled for a client, all the read only queries are assumed
    # to be cached: this will force Redis to store information in the invalidation
    # table. When keys are modified, such information is flushed away, and
    # invalidation messages are sent to the clients. However if the workload is
    # heavily dominated by reads, Redis could use more and more memory in order
    # to track the keys fetched by many clients.
    #
    # For this reason it is possible to configure a maximum fill value for the
    # invalidation table. By default it is set to 1M of keys, and once this limit
    # is reached, Redis will start to evict keys in the invalidation table
    # even if they were not modified, just to reclaim memory: this will in turn
    # force the clients to invalidate the cached values. Basically the table
    # maximum size is a trade off between the memory you want to spend server
    # side to track information about who cached what, and the ability of clients
    # to retain cached objects in memory.
    #
    # If you set the value to 0, it means there are no limits, and Redis will
    # retain as many keys as needed in the invalidation table.
    # In the "stats" INFO section, you can find information about the number of
    # keys in the invalidation table at every given moment.
    #
    # Note: when key tracking is used in broadcasting mode, no memory is used
    # in the server side so this setting is useless.
    #
    # tracking-table-max-keys 1000000
    ################################## SECURITY ###################################
    # Warning: since Redis is pretty fast an outside user can try up to
    # 1 million passwords per second against a modern box. This means that you
    # should use very strong passwords, otherwise they will be very easy to break.
    # Note that because the password is really a shared secret between the client
    # and the server, and should not be memorized by any human, the password
    # can be easily a long string from /dev/urandom or whatever, so by using a
    # long and unguessable password no brute force attack will be possible.
    # Redis ACL users are defined in the following format:
    #
    #   user <username> ... acl rules ...
    #
    # For example:
    #
    #   user worker +@list +@connection ~jobs:* on >ffa9203c493aa99
    #
    # The special username "default" is used for new connections. If this user
    # has the "nopass" rule, then new connections will be immediately authenticated
    # as the "default" user without the need of any password provided via the
    # AUTH command. Otherwise if the "default" user is not flagged with "nopass"
    # the connections will start in not authenticated state, and will require
    # AUTH (or the HELLO command AUTH option) in order to be authenticated and
    # start to work.
    #
    # The ACL rules that describe what an user can do are the following:
    #
    #  on           Enable the user: it is possible to authenticate as this user.
    #  off          Disable the user: it's no longer possible to authenticate
    #               with this user, however the already authenticated connections
    #               will still work.
    #  +<command>   Allow the execution of that command
    #  -<command>   Disallow the execution of that command
    #  +@<category> Allow the execution of all the commands in such category
    #               with valid categories are like @admin, @set, @sortedset, ...
    #               and so forth, see the full list in the server.c file where
    #               the Redis command table is described and defined.
    #               The special category @all means all the commands, but currently
    #               present in the server, and that will be loaded in the future
    #               via modules.
    #  +<command>|subcommand    Allow a specific subcommand of an otherwise
    #                           disabled command. Note that this form is not
    #                           allowed as negative like -DEBUG|SEGFAULT, but
    #                           only additive starting with "+".
    #  allcommands  Alias for +@all. Note that it implies the ability to execute
    #               all the future commands loaded via the modules system.
    #  nocommands   Alias for -@all.
    #  ~<pattern>   Add a pattern of keys that can be mentioned as part of
    #               commands. For instance ~* allows all the keys. The pattern
    #               is a glob-style pattern like the one of KEYS.
    #               It is possible to specify multiple patterns.
    #  allkeys      Alias for ~*
    #  resetkeys    Flush the list of allowed keys patterns.
    #  ><password>  Add this passowrd to the list of valid password for the user.
    #               For example >mypass will add "mypass" to the list.
    #               This directive clears the "nopass" flag (see later).
    #  <<password>  Remove this password from the list of valid passwords.
    #  nopass       All the set passwords of the user are removed, and the user
    #               is flagged as requiring no password: it means that every
    #               password will work against this user. If this directive is
    #               used for the default user, every new connection will be
    #               immediately authenticated with the default user without
    #               any explicit AUTH command required. Note that the "resetpass"
    #               directive will clear this condition.
    #  resetpass    Flush the list of allowed passwords. Moreover removes the
    #               "nopass" status. After "resetpass" the user has no associated
    #               passwords and there is no way to authenticate without adding
    #               some password (or setting it as "nopass" later).
    #  reset        Performs the following actions: resetpass, resetkeys, off,
    #               -@all. The user returns to the same state it has immediately
    #               after its creation.
    #
    # ACL rules can be specified in any order: for instance you can start with
    # passwords, then flags, or key patterns. However note that the additive
    # and subtractive rules will CHANGE MEANING depending on the ordering.
    # For instance see the following example:
    #
    #   user alice on +@all -DEBUG ~* >somepassword
    #
    # This will allow "alice" to use all the commands with the exception of the
    # DEBUG command, since +@all added all the commands to the set of the commands
    # alice can use, and later DEBUG was removed. However if we invert the order
    # of two ACL rules the result will be different:
    #
    #   user alice on -DEBUG +@all ~* >somepassword
    #
    # Now DEBUG was removed when alice had yet no commands in the set of allowed
    # commands, later all the commands are added, so the user will be able to
    # execute everything.
    #
    # Basically ACL rules are processed left-to-right.
    #
    # For more information about ACL configuration please refer to
    # the Redis web site at https://redis.io/topics/acl
    # ACL LOG
    #
    # The ACL Log tracks failed commands and authentication events associated
    # with ACLs. The ACL Log is useful to troubleshoot failed commands blocked
    # by ACLs. The ACL Log is stored in memory. You can reclaim memory with
    # ACL LOG RESET. Define the maximum entry length of the ACL Log below.
    acllog-max-len 128
    # Using an external ACL file
    #
    # Instead of configuring users here in this file, it is possible to use
    # a stand-alone file just listing users. The two methods cannot be mixed:
    # if you configure users here and at the same time you activate the exteranl
    # ACL file, the server will refuse to start.
    #
    # The format of the external ACL user file is exactly the same as the
    # format that is used inside redis.conf to describe users.
    #
    # aclfile /etc/redis/users.acl
    # IMPORTANT NOTE: starting with Redis 6 "requirepass" is just a compatiblity
    # layer on top of the new ACL system. The option effect will be just setting
    # the password for the default user. Clients will still authenticate using
    # AUTH <password> as usually, or more explicitly with AUTH default <password>
    # if they follow the new protocol: both will work.
    #
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: redis-scripts-config-map
data:

  sentinel_init.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash
    REDIS_NODES= "redis-0.redis,redis-1.redis,redis-2.redis"
    for i in ${REDIS_NODES//,/ }
    do
        echo "finding master at $i"
        MASTER=$(redis-cli --no-auth-warning --raw -h $i -a ${REDIS_PASSWORD} info replication | awk '{print $1}' | grep master_host: | cut -d ":" -f2)
    
        if [ "${MASTER}" == "" ]; then
            echo "no master found"
            MASTER=
        else
            echo "found ${MASTER}"
            break
        fi
    
    done

    POD_FQDN=$(hostname -f)
    echo "sentinel monitor mymaster ${MASTER} 6379 2" >> /tmp/master
    echo "port 5000
    $(cat /tmp/master)
    protected-mode no
    sentinel resolve-hostnames yes
    sentinel announce-hostnames yes
    sentinel announce-ip $POD_FQDN
    sentinel announce-port 5000
    sentinel down-after-milliseconds mymaster 1000
    sentinel failover-timeout mymaster 60000
    sentinel parallel-syncs mymaster 1
    sentinel sentinel-pass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    sentinel auth-pass mymaster ${REDIS_PASSWORD}
    requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}

    " > /etc/redis/sentinel.conf
    cat /etc/redis/sentinel.conf


  redis_init.sh: |
    #!/bin/bash

    cp /tmp/redis/redis.conf /etc/redis/redis.conf
    echo "requirepass ${REDIS_PASSWORD}" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
    echo "masterauth ${REDIS_PASSWORD}" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
    echo "replica-announce-ip ${HOSTNAME}.redis" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
    echo "replica-announce-port 6379 " >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
    
    echo "finding master..."

    if [ "$(timeout 5 redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 -a ${REDIS_PASSWORD} ping)" != "PONG" ]; then

      echo "sentinel not found, defaulting to redis-0"

      if [ ${HOSTNAME} == "redis-0" ]; then
        echo "this is redis-0, not updating config..."
      else
        echo "updating redis.conf..."
        echo "repl-ping-replica-period 3" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
        echo "slave-read-only no" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
        echo "slaveof redis-0.redis 6379" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
      fi

    else

      echo "sentinel found, finding master"
      MASTER="$(redis-cli -h sentinel -p 5000 -a ${REDIS_PASSWORD} sentinel get-master-addr-by-name mymaster | grep -E '(^redis-*)|([0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3})')"

      if [ "${HOSTNAME}.redis" == ${MASTER} ]; then
        echo "this is master, not updating config..."
      else
        echo "master found : ${MASTER}, updating redis.conf"
        echo "slave-read-only no" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
        echo "slaveof ${MASTER} 6379" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
        echo "repl-ping-replica-period 3" >> /etc/redis/redis.conf
      fi

    fi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: redis-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  REDIS_PASSWORD: c3BlZWR5R29uemFsZXMyMDIz
---
# Headless service so sentinel could access redisses using syntax <pod-name>.<service-name>

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: redis
  labels:
    app: redis
    app.kubernetes.io/component: redis
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: redis
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
    - port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
      name: redis
  selector:
    app: redis

---

# Sentinel service used for project pod connection

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: sentinel-redis
  labels:
    app: sentinel
    app.kubernetes.io/component: sentinel
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: sentinel
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  sessionAffinity: None
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      targetPort: 5000
      name: sentinel
  selector:
    app: sentinel
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: redis
spec:
  serviceName: redis
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: redis
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: redis
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: config
          image: 'scorenexus.isbank:8443/bitnami/redis:7.0'
          env:
            - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: redis-secret
                  key: REDIS_PASSWORD
          command: [ "sh", "-c", "/scripts/redis_init.sh" ]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: redis-config
              mountPath: /etc/redis/
            - name: config
              mountPath: /tmp/redis/
            - name: init-script
              mountPath: /scripts/
      containers:
        - name: redis
          image: 'scorenexus.isbank:8443/bitnami/redis:7.0'
          command: ["redis-server"]
          args: ["/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 6379
              name: redis
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
            - name: redis-config
              mountPath: /etc/redis/
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: redis-config
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: init-script
          configMap:
            name: redis-scripts-config-map
            defaultMode: 0777
            items:
              - key: redis_init.sh
                path: redis_init.sh
        - name: config
          configMap:
            name: redis-config-map
            items:
              - key: redis.conf
                path: redis.conf
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: sentinel-redis
spec:
  serviceName: sentinel-redis
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sentinel
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sentinel
    spec:
      initContainers:
        - name: config
          image: 'scorenexus.isbank:8443/bitnami/redis:7.0'
          env:
            - name: REDIS_NODES
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: redis-config-map
                  key: REDIS_NODES
            - name: REDIS_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: redis-secret
                  key: REDIS_PASSWORD
          command: [ "sh", "-c", "/scripts/sentinel_init.sh" ]
          volumeMounts:
            - name: redis-config
              mountPath: /etc/redis/
            - name: init-script
              mountPath: /scripts/
      containers:
        - name: sentinel
          image: 'scorenexus.isbank:8443/bitnami/redis:7.0'
          command: ["redis-sentinel"]
          args: ["/etc/redis/sentinel.conf"]
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
              name: sentinel
          volumeMounts:
            - name: redis-config
              mountPath: /etc/redis/
            - name: data
              mountPath: /data
      volumes:
        - name: init-script
          configMap:
            name: redis-scripts-config-map
            defaultMode: 0777
            items:
              - key: sentinel_init.sh
                path: sentinel_init.sh
        - name: redis-config
          emptyDir: {}
        - name: data
          emptyDir: {}
---
```